# Negligible probability of failure in correctness definition (predicate based encryption)

Tags: encryption, predicate-encryption

I would like to understand why some definitions of correctness allow a negligible failure probability. i.e. the probability that decryption reverses encryption is 1 minus a negligibly small amount.

I have noticed in the Katz, Sahai, Waters Predicate based encryption scheme that when defining correctness in the two cases where either the predicate is satisfied when trying to decrypt or when the predicate is not satisfied, there is a small failure probability only in the case when the predicate is not satisfied (I have attached an image of this).

[image: Katz, Sahai, Waters correctness of PBE]

What is the reason for the negligible probability of failure in the second case?

Comment: What are $F$ and $\Sigma$?

Comment: In response to @user2768... The F represents a set of predicates (where a predicate f is associated with a ciphertext) and Sigma is the set of attributes (associated with a secret key). So in the first case we have the predicate being on the ciphertext being satisfied by the attributes on the secret key (allowing decryption) and in the second case the predicate is not satisfied by the attributes on the secret key (prohibiting decryption).

Comment: Are you asking why that particular predicate based encryption scheme tolerates negligible failures in the second case, but not in the first? Or why negligible failure is tolerated more generally (e.g., in many correctness definitions)?

Comment: In response to @user2768... Both cases. In general why would you sometimes add the negligible probability of failure in a correctness definition? Furthermore, more specifically why would there be a negligible probability of failure in the second case of the Predicate Encryption correctness example, but not the first? In the Predicate encryption example i thought it might have something to do with false negatives when evaluating the predicate? But I wasnt sure.

Comment: @George Perhaps you can edit your question to ask the two questions separately. Regarding the former: we needn't care about failures of correctness that occur with negligible probability, because they aren't observed in practice. Thus, we opt for a more general definition of correctness that tolerates such failures.